# loop into input array field and change input fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, input, duplicates

I would like to collect the list of inputs filed as arrays using name="Item[fields][x]".
My form:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
    <input id="player_name661" type="text" name="Item[fields][1]" value=""><a href="#" id="clone1" name="dup1" >Use same</a><br />
    <input id="player_name662" type="text" name="Item[fields][2]" value=""><a href="#" id="clone2" name="dup2" >Use same</a><br />
    <input id="player_name663" type="text" name="Item[fields][3]" value=""><a href="#" id="clone3" name="dup3" >Use same</a><br />
    <input id="player_name664" type="text" name="Item[fields][4]" value=""><br />
    <input id="player_name665" type="text" name="Item[fields][5]" value=""><br />
     ....
    <input id="player_name66x"" type="text" name="Item[fields][x]" >
    </form>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
for ($i=1; i < (Item[fields].length+1)/3; $i++) { 
   var myinput = $("Item[fields][1]").val();
   $("input[name^='fields][1+3(i)]").val(myinput); 
}
```

changes are done in multiples of 3.
Note: i can only use name attribute, no id or class. So clicking :

```
dup1, clone field[1] into [4],[7] ...[1+3(i)]  

dup2, clone field[2] into [5],[8],...[2+3(i)] 

dup3, clone field[3] into [6],[9],...[3+3(i)]
```

Comment: Do you want to give the value of the first of each 3 to the 2nd and 3rd of each group of 3 inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var all_inputs = $("input[name^=Item\\[fields\\]]");
for (i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == '0') {  
        var val = all_inputs.eq(i).val();  //get the new value for each group of 3  
    }
    all_inputs.eq(i).val(val); //assign the value to inputs in this group of 3
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6ZPe/2/)**

Comment: Is a bracket missing in "input[name^=Item\\[fields\\]")? all_inputs.length returns zero

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign, yes it "was" :) - corrected. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This is very close! Thanks- I think it is something like this 

    `if (i % 3 == 0) {  var val = all_inputs.eq(i).val();}
    if (i % 3 == 1) {  var val = all_inputs.eq(i).val();}
    if (i % 3 == 2) {  var val = all_inputs.eq(i).val();}
    Because, 
    dup1, clone field[1] into [4],[7] ...[1+3(i)]  
    dup2, clone field[2] into [5],[8],...[2+3(i)] 
    dup3, clone field[3] into [6],[9],...[3+3(i)]`

But it is not working..
ANd my script still return 0, but on JSFIDLE it works:

Comment: $("#clone1").click(function() {    
 var all_inputs = $("input[name^=Item\\[fields\\]");
 alert (all_inputs.length); 
 for (i = 0; i < all_inputs.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == '0') {  
   var val = all_inputs.eq(i).val();  //get the new value for each group of 3  
  }
  all_inputs.eq(i).val(val); //assign the value to inputs in this group of 3
 }

Comment: I had to change my JQuery from 1.4.4  to 1.10.1 an it worked!
Here is my final script.. I have one script for each of the 3 buttons #clone1, #clone2 and #clone3

 `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clone1").click(function () {
        var all_inputs = $("input[name^=Item\\[fields\\]]");
        for (i = 3; i < all_inputs.length; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == '0') {var val = all_inputs.eq(0).val();
   all_inputs.eq(i).val(val);} 
            
        }
    });`

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign, great! I didn't notice you had jQuery 1.4, good that you saw that :)